# "Get" Method and Constructors Exercise Problem in Java

Tags: java, constructor

The code is supposed to get the required bedrooms, bathrooms, and rent from the user and show him the apartments that fit their needs. The code is working, but it asks questions 5 times instead of just once and just gives the information for each apartment at the time. For example, if I want an apartment with 3 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms, and the rent 300, it will just ask again the second time, without showing me the error message "Apartment number " + aptNumber + " isn't suitable for your needs."

I just want it to work once, asking one time and giving the list of every apartment that is suitable. If anyone has any ideas please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apartment
{
   private int aptNumber;
   private int bedrooms;
   private int baths;
   private double rent;

   public int getAptNumber()
   {
       return aptNumber;
   }

   public int getBedrooms()
   {
       return bedrooms;
   }

   public int getBaths()
   {
       return baths;
   }

   public double getRent()
   {
       return rent;
   }

   public Apartment(int num, int bed, int bath, double ren)
   {
       aptNumber = num;
       bedrooms = bed;
       baths = bath;
       rent = ren;
   }

   public Apartment(int num, int bed, int bath)
   {
       this(num, bed, bath, 300);
   }

   public Apartment(int num, int bed)
   {
       this(num, bed, 2);
   }

   public Apartment(int num)
   {
       this(num, 2);
   }

   public void display()
   {
       int minbeds;
       int minbaths;
       double maxrent;

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Please enter: least amount of bedrooms >> ");
       minbeds = input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Please enter: least amount of bathrooms >> ");
       minbaths = input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Please enter: maximum amount of rent >> ");
       maxrent = input.nextDouble();

       if(minbeds <= bedrooms) {
           if(minbaths <= baths) {
               if(maxrent >= rent) {
                   System.out.println("Apartment number " + aptNumber + " has " + bedrooms + 
                                      " bedrooms, " + baths + " bathrooms and the rent is " + rent);
               }
            }
        }
       else if (minbeds > bedrooms) {
           System.out.println("Apartment number " + aptNumber + " isn't suitable for your needs.");
       }
       else if (minbaths > baths) {
           System.out.println("Apartment number " + aptNumber + " isn't suitable for your needs.");
       }
       else if (maxrent < rent) {
           System.out.println("Apartment number " + aptNumber + " isn't suitable for your needs.");
       }
   }    
}





public class ApartmentProperties
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
      Apartment first = new Apartment(1);
      Apartment second = new Apartment(2, 2);
      Apartment third = new Apartment(3, 3, 2, 400);
      Apartment fourth = new Apartment(4, 1, 1, 250);
      Apartment fifth = new Apartment(5, 1, 1, 200);    

      first.display();
      second.display();
      third.display();
      fourth.display();
      fifth.display();
   }
}
```

Comment: Make `display` a static method and make it take and array of Apartment objects as argument

Comment: Don't make new Scanners each time. Pass the Scanner in as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I moved display method from Apartment to ApartmentProperties class, made it static and put list of apartments in arguments.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Apartment {
    private int aptNumber;
    private int bedrooms;
    private int baths;
    private double rent;

    public int getAptNumber() {
        return aptNumber;
    }

    public int getBedrooms() {
        return bedrooms;
    }

    public int getBaths() {
        return baths;
    }

    public double getRent() {
        return rent;
    }

    public Apartment(int num, int bed, int bath, double ren) {
        aptNumber = num;
        bedrooms = bed;
        baths = bath;
        rent = ren;
    }

    public Apartment(int num, int bed, int bath) {
        this(num, bed, bath, 300);
    }

    public Apartment(int num, int bed) {
        this(num, bed, 2);
    }

    public Apartment(int num) {
        this(num, 2);
    }
}

public class ApartmentProperties {
    public static void display(List<Apartment> apartmentList) {
        int minbeds;
        int minbaths;
        double maxrent;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter: least amount of bedrooms >> ");
        minbeds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter: least amount of bathrooms >> ");
        minbaths = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter: maximum amount of rent >> ");
        maxrent = input.nextDouble();

        boolean apartmentIsFound = false;
        for (Apartment apartment : apartmentList) {
            if (minbeds <= apartment.getBedrooms() && minbaths <= apartment.getBaths()
                    && maxrent >= apartment.getRent()) {
                System.out.println("Apartment number " + apartment.getAptNumber() + " has " + apartment.getBedrooms() +
                        " bedrooms, " + apartment.getBaths() + " bathrooms and the rent is " + apartment.getRent());
                apartmentIsFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (apartmentIsFound == false) {
            System.out.println("There are no apartments with those requirements");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apartment first = new Apartment(1);
        Apartment second = new Apartment(2, 2);
        Apartment third = new Apartment(3, 3, 2, 400);
        Apartment fourth = new Apartment(4, 1, 1, 250);
        Apartment fifth = new Apartment(5, 1, 1, 200);

        List<Apartment> apartmentList = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
        apartmentList.add(first);
        apartmentList.add(second);
        apartmentList.add(third);
        apartmentList.add(fourth);
        apartmentList.add(fifth);

        display(apartmentList);
    }
}
```

Comment: that works, thank you, but i wasn't really clear with what the exercise needs exactly. So, whenever the user gives information for their required apartment, it should either give him a list of all the suiting apartments or a message that says "there are no apartments with those requirements". Im sorry, english isn't my first language so I couldn't explain it properly. Can you help me with that also? The If's have me confused :(

Comment: I updated the code in the answer. It's ok, english is my third :)